# Is there a maximum number of labels that can be created in a GitHub repo?

Tags: github, github-issues

I've been looking at the [GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/using-labels-and-milestones-to-track-work/managing-labels) but haven't found a `maximum` number specified anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this using the GitHub API to add labels to a repository: I was able to add **more than ten thousand labels**, without getting any errors.

Since the [GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/labels?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-label) only allows for adding labels one at a time, the process was a bit time-consuming and I hit [API rate limits](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/using-the-rest-api/rate-limits-for-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28) twice during the process, so I concluded my test after hitting the second rate limit, at which point there were 10,501 labels added to the repository, and I could still add more.

### Reproduce

Here is how you can reproduce the experiment in Python:

1. Install `PyLinks` for communicating with the GitHub API (disclaimer: I am the author):

```bash
pip install pylinks
```

2. Run the following script:

```py
import pylinks
import itertools

GITHUB_USERNAME = "YOUR GITHUB USERNAME HERE"
GITHUB_REPO = "YOUR GITHUB REPOSITORY NAME HERE"
PAT = "YOUR PERSONAL ACCESS TOKEN HERE"
NUM_LABELS = 11000  # Number of labels to add to the repo

def create_unique_strings(n):
    """Generate n unique strings with the minimum possible length
    by using combinations of lowercase letters.
    """
    # Limiting the characters to lowercase to ensure the strings are as short as possible
    characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    # Start with the shortest possible strings (length 1)
    length = 1
    # List to store the unique strings
    unique_strings = []
    while len(unique_strings) < n:
        # Generate all combinations of the current length
        for s in itertools.product(characters, repeat=length):
            unique_string = ''.join(s)
            unique_strings.append(unique_string)
            if len(unique_strings) == n:
                break
        # Increase the length for the next iteration
        length += 1
    return unique_strings

gh_api = pylinks.api.github(PAT).user(GITHUB_USERNAME).repo(GITHUB_REPO)
labels = create_unique_strings(NUM_LABELS)
for label in labels:
    gh_api.label_create(label)
```

As I mentioned, you will be hit by rate limits after every ca. 5000 labels, so you'll have to wait a while and then continue with the remaining of the labels each time.

### Notes

I also tested how many labels can be added to one issue/pull request: There you have a limit of max. 100 labels.
To reproduce this, add the following code to the script above:

```py
ISSUE_OR_PR_NUMBER = 123  # The number of an existing issue/pr in the repository

gh_api.issue_labels_set(ISSUE_OR_PR_NUMBER, unique_strings[:100])  # This will pass

gh_api.issue_labels_set(ISSUE_OR_PR_NUMBER, unique_strings[:101])  # This will fail with status code 422 and reason 'Unprocessable Entity'
```